# Could not find a declaration file for module 'classnames'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code

When I trying `import cn from 'classnames'` I see this error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'classnames'. 'C:/Users/Demian/Desktop/udemy/react+next/top-app/node_modules/classnames/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/classnames` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'classnames';`
```

`npm i --save-dev @types/classnames` and creating `.d.ts` file with `declare module 'classnames';` from error-log not helping

The other variants like `npm install -D @types/module-name` or `npm install @types/module-name` from StackOverflow are also not so much helpful. After them I see another error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fmodule-name - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@types/module-name@latest' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)        
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

Another variant I tried - `npm i -D @types/classnames`. It proceeds but also does not help

My tsconfig.json:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My package.json:

```json
{
    "name": "top-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "debug": "set NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect && next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "stylelint": "stylelint \"**/*.css\" --fix"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/classnames": "^2.3.1",
        "@types/react-router": "^5.1.16",
        "classnames": "^2.3.1",
        "next": "11.1.0",
        "react": "17.0.2",
        "react-dom": "17.0.2",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.14.5",
        "@types/react": "^17.0.19",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.29.3",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.29.3",
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "eslint-config-next": "11.1.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.1",
        "prettier": "^2.3.2",
        "stylelint": "^13.13.1",
        "stylelint-config-standard": "^22.0.0",
        "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
        "stylelint-order-config-standard": "^0.1.3",
        "typescript": "^4.4.2"
    }
}
```

What should I do? Please not beat if it is too easy problem

Comment: are using any specific configurations for your project or you yourself set it up? can you also add the `tsconfig.json` to the post

Comment: No, I change it only a little. But I add it

Comment: i think there is no type definitions files for the package you are using (check it out). if thats the case you can change `allowJS` to `true` and you are able to use the package just like we use it in javascript, or create your own type definitions. can you also tell what package you are trying to use?

Comment: I use only the default package.json(I upload it in above). But I surely don't know why I should use allow js?  I use typescript for the all project. But your no type definition I surely don't know. Do you mean package manager? If this, I use npm

Comment: All works! It was just an error in my code(I used = instead of ==). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was just an obvious error:

```js
<button
        className={cn(styles.button, {
        [styles.primary]: appearance == 'primary',// I used '=' instead of '=='
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
        [styles.ghost]: appearance == 'ghost',
    })}
>
```